# Automatic phone number dialing with windows 8 phone

Tags: windows-phone-8

I would like to know if it is possible to automatically dial a phone number (911) within an app in Windows Phone 8. Using href I can bring up the dialer with the number but the user still has to manually press dial (inconvenient when in need for immediate assistance).

```
<a href="tel:+15555555555">Call me at +1 (555) 555-5555</a>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, actions such as making a phone call or sending a text (via the phone's SIM card and not a web service) requires user interaction with the current SDK. This seems to be a security design as it prevents malicious apps from secretly sending texts or dialling premium rate numbers without the user's knowledge.

Comment: It does make sense. I know that iOS is also preventing this but I've seem BlackBerry 7 apps doing it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with BlackBerry native dev but Android supports the ability to bypass user interaction.